# Visual Web Part in Sharepoint 2010 shows only XMLDataSource in GridView

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I created a new Visual Web Part in VS 2010 (using Sharepoint Server 2010), then dropped a GridView on the User Control.
However when setting up the DataSource for the GridView, I only get XMLDataSource as an option.
There is no option to create a SQLDataSource for instance.

does anyone know how to get over this limitation in Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access some sort of on-premise SQL server, you might want to look into [BCS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx).  Alternatively, you can also bind your grid to any datasource in the codebehind of your visual web part.  For example, you can bind it to a ADO datatable.